# Utilize a bootstrap modal for both creating and editing users

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I have a view which contains two elements :

1. Button : A `add` button to create a row for the table
2. Table : A table that I populate dynamically from database, on each row I have an edit button

What I want to do is when I click on the `add` button it shows a modal with form (`lastname`, `firstname`, `role`, `login` etc)
and when I click on `edit` button (row in table) it open the same modal but with all attributes of the user in the form.

my view `Users.blade.php`

```
 ....
// include modal
@include('CreateOrEditModal', array('user' => isset($user) ? $user: null))

// add button
<button data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#create_edit_modal" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add user</button>
 ...
 ...
<tbody>
    @foreach($users as $user)               
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->role}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->login}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->password}}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#create_edit_modal" data="{{$user}}"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>Edit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

my modal

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="create_edit_modal" tabindex="-1"  aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
         @if(isset($user))
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{$user->name}}</h4>
         @else
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add a new user</h4>
         @endif
      </div>
     <div class="modal-body"> 
                @if(isset($user))
                    {!! Form::model($user, array('class' => 'form-horizontal','route' => array('site.update', $user->id), 'method' => 'PUT')); !!}
                @else
                    {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'site','class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}
                @endif
                <div class="row">
                 ....
```

Comment: I improved the formatting and reworded a couple of sentences for better readability. Please add what  you have tried so far to your question and mention why it is not working. This can be done clearing any inputs in the modal and retrieving the data from the row whose edit button is clicked and set those values to the inputs in the modal using javascript or jquery.

Comment: Do you have any experience with javascript? I'd make an ajax call to populate the modal (or plain jQuery to grab the data from the table)

Comment: No i'm new to Javascript, i have no idea how can i do this :(